# Import Winreg in a Python Script

Tags: python, winreg

I am currently working on a Jenkins freestyle job and one of the build steps is to run a Python script. I have been working on this job for a couple of days now and this is one of the last build steps needed to finish it off. I have reached a point where I get an error letting me know that the **import winreg** module does not exist.

I have installed Jenkins on CentOS and have read some documentation stating that I am unable to import this module on this distribution.

Is there no other way to solve this than to switch over to a Windows machine?

Thanks

Comment: The point of winreg is to modify the windows registry. What would be the point of using it on a centos machine?

Comment: Also, [**`winreg`**](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/winreg.html) only exists on windows for Python 3. It's called [**`_winreg`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) on Python 2

Comment: Maybe he installed `wine` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, the [_winreg docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#module-_winreg) says:

> These functions expose the Windows registry API to Python.

You could try to make it run on a windows virtual machine in your centos host or just following the official [Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions) guide